# How to graph the motion of a projectile?

Tags: physics, graphing-functions, kinematics, projectile-motion

Suppose I have a projectile, fired at angle $\theta$, with velocity $v_0$, assuming it's only acted upon by gravity. How can I find an equation to enable me to plot the motion (vertical height against time) on a graph (I'll be doing this computationally)

Comment: It's a classical problem, you can find the solution in every Physics book. Are you interested to derive it by yourself?

Comment: Refer for example to [Projectile motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion).

Comment: The answer to this does not come from mathematics, but from physics ...

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the parametric equation of the trajectory.

With units in feet and seconds we get the following equations.

Note that your $$x(t)=(v_0 \cos \theta )t$$

and your $$y(t)= -16 t^2+(v_0 \sin \theta )t +x_0$$

Comment: Thanks I will edit my answer